# Media files links in wordpress broken?

Tags: php, wordpress, media-library

I have a problem in my Wordpress site. When I upload file or image by Add New in "media library" and open the url that the Wordpress gets and open it in a new tab it gets this page :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQebz.jpg)

and can't open the file!
and I cant use its url in pages..
But in the case of image it save in server more than one version of the image like 'img.jpg' >> 'img-90x90.jpg' and 'img-90x65.jpg' etc., The url of this image is working well without any problem !
And if I uploaded image to the server manually by FTP Account it works well.

I works on WordPress 4.7.1

Thanks a lot for help in advance :)

Comment: Maybe the image size that you are uploading is to big?

Comment: the 500 means a server error, so you should find the error log and see what it is trying to tell you.

Comment: @TomaszSwider OK. I will see it now.

Comment: @TomaszSwider it gets this error:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (URL Rewrite Module Error.)
in the url of the img !

Comment: @MarioSanchezMaselli I already changed it from wp-config.php >> " define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M'); ", but I guess the problem isn't here because that happens with any file be uploaded regardless its size big or small :/ thanks ^.^

Comment: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500" it sounds like something that javascript would say, did you get it from the browser dev tools? You need to look in Wordpress error log or the http server error log.